# GetLocalResourceObject inside web api controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms, localization, resources

I am unable to get the correct path to my resource file from within the web api controller. My controller is inside a Controllers folder and the resources are in controls/App_LocalResources/ResourceName/ResourceName.ascx.resx etc

So I have tried many similar calls like this

```
HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/controls/MyResource/MyResource.ascx", "Company", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

and I always get InvalidOperationException with the message "The resource class for this page was not found.  Please check if the resource file exists and try again.".

How can I retrieve the right path?

[image: vs folder structure]

Comment: Try remove "~" from path

Comment: same error unfortunately

Comment: Try also "~/MyResource.ascx"  instead "~/controls/MyResource/MyResource.ascx"

Comment: I must have tried literally every f..... way

Comment: But you need use virtual path like "~/Resource.ascx" and it should be work perfect.

Comment: I gave up and used the global resource object which requires no path.